# Is there a shorter way to retrieve the full path of a file but without its extension?

Tags: powershell, path

I am using this:

```
$DestFilePath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test Fonts\Helvetica Now Display Black.ttf"

$FullPathNoExtension = [Path]::Combine([Path]::GetDirectoryName($DestFilePath),[Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($DestFilePath))
```

`$FullPathNoExtension` is now
`"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test Fonts\Helvetica Now Display Black"`

Is there a shorter way to accomplish this without some kind of helper method? It's really verbose and kind of ugly.

Any reccommendations greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of this action is? Whatfor or why do you need a full path but without an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
$DestFilePath = [System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test Fonts\Helvetica Now Display Black.ttf"

$FullPathNoExtension = "{0}\{1}" -f $DestFilePath.DirectoryName, $DestFilePath.baseName
```

Comment: This is elegant, but has a fundamental limitation: it only works with paths that are _already full paths_. It doesn't work (reliably) with _relative_ input paths, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's. For instance, `Set-Location C:\Windows; ([System.IO.FileInfo] '.\win.ini').FullName` does _not_ yield `C:\Windows\win.ini`, as one might expect, but something like `C:\Users\jdoe\winini`, because it is resolved against the process-level working directory that .NET operates on, which is unaffected by `Set-Location`.

Comment: I mean, yeah. But OP used an explicit full path in their question, so I was expecting the full path being known, or at least knowable. Specific solution to specific problem.

Comment: Yes, the sample path is absolute, and maybe that is truly what the OP assumes, but, given the wording of the question and its ambiguity, it is likely that future readers _will_ look for relative path resolution, so the limitation of the approach is worth stating prominently, as part of the answer (people tend to ignore comments). As an aside: `Join-Path $DestFilePath.DirectoryName $DestFilePath.baseName` would work too (with full paths).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by finding index of `.` and then `substring` to that position. Something like this:

```
$FullPathNoExtension = $filePath.Substring(0, $filePath.LastIndexOf('.'))
```

You can add check if there is `.` in name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
$DestFilePath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test Fonts\Helvetica Now Display Black.ttf"

$FullPathNoExtension = $DestFilePath -replace '\.\w+$'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to combine two different operations:

- Determining a potentially *relative* input path's *full* path.
- Removing the extension, if any, from a file name.

The **shortest PowerShell-idiomatic solution** I can think of:

```bash
# NOTE: Works with *existing* paths only - see below.
(Convert-Path -LiteralPath $DestFilePath) -replace '\.[^.]*$'
```

[`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) converts a given path to a *full, file-system-native* one, and the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation uses a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) to trim any filename extension from the result (removes everything starting with the last `.`, if there is one).

**If you prefer to avoid `-replace`** in favor of calling a .NET API, use [`[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension) as follows (omitting the optional-in-PowerShell `System.` prefix for brevity):

```bash
[IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(
  (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $DestFilePath), 
  [NullString]::Value
)
```

<sup>Note: The method requires an actual `null` value in order to *remove* the extension; from PowerShell, for technical reasons, you must pass the special `[NullString]::Value` singleton to achieve that, because PowerShell by default converts a `$null` passed to .NET method's `string` parameter to the *empty string*.</sup>

If you want to resolve [*wildcard*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based paths to matching, literal full paths, use `-Path` instead of `-LiteralPath`
(`-Path` is the positionally implied default parameter, so you may omit it; this usually also works for *literal* input paths, but note that in PowerShell it isn't just `*` and `?` that are wildcard metacharacters, but also `[` and `]`, so literal paths that include the latter *must* be passed with `-LiteralPath`).

However, `Convert-Path`, like the related [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) cmdlet,<sup>[1]</sup> has a major limitation: it **only works with *existing* paths**.

- [GitHub issue #2993](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2993) is a long-standing feature request dating back to 2017 to allow resolving even *non-existent* paths to full paths, such as a not-yet-existent *output* file in the current directory, say, `.\out.txt`, on an *opt-in* basis, via a new switch, say, `-SkipValidation`.
  Unfortunately, even though the request was green-lit in principle, the discussion around it has stalled as of this writing.

---

If you need a **solution for (potentially) *non-existent* (yet-to-be-created) paths**, you can use the - obscure -  **`$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath()`** method:

```bash
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(
  $DestFilePath
) -replace '\.[^.]*$'
```

Like `Convert-Path`, this method expresses the resulting path as a *file-system-native* one.

---

<sup>[1] Both cmdlets work not only with *file-system* paths, but also with those of other PowerShell [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers). When the provider underlying the *current [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Locations)* is a *file-system* location (directory), it is used to resolve the given paths to full paths.

The cmdlets differ in that `Convert-Path` returns full paths as provider-*native* paths, whereas `Resolve-Path` returns [`System.Management.Automation.PathInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PathInfo) instances expressed in terms of *PowerShell drives*.

However, not all file system-related PowerShell drives are *file-system-native ones* (`C:` being an example of the latter), because PowerShell allows you to define arbitrary PowerShell-only drives with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) (`Temp:` being an example of the latter in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

In other words: If the current location is on a PowerShell-only drive, `Resolve-Path` expresses resolved paths in terms of this drive, whereas `Convert-Path` expresses them in terms of the underlying file-system-*native* drive, which makes them suitable for use *outside* of PowerShell.</sup>